# Having first image in a cycle slideshow fadein?

Tags: jquery, cycle

I'm trying to have my first image of a jQuery cycle slideshow fade in at:  [Slide Show test](http://test3.chuprinastudios.com)

The code I'm using is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#slideshow img:first').fadeIn(20000, function() {
              $('#slideshow').cycle({
                 fx: 'fadeZoom', 
                 timeout: 8000,
                 speed:  6000,
              });
   });
});
```

Unforunately it isn't working.  What am I missing?  What mistake have I made?  Any help, guidance or code snippets would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
PChuprina

Comment: Try keeping the first image hidden whiling loading the page and then call the `.show()` before the `fadeIn()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fading in the image, but you should be fading in the div.

So change `img` to `div`.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the following?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#slideshow img:first').fadeOut(0);
   $('#slideshow img:first').fadeIn(20000, function() {
              $('#slideshow').cycle({
                 fx: 'fadeZoom', 
                 timeout: 8000,
                 speed:  6000,
              });
   });
});
```